# "Get Available Generators List" warning in RubyMine. How do I get rid of this?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rubymine

I am using RubyMine 5.4.1 and was creating a new rails `3.2.9` application using ruby `1.9.3-p0`, and received the below warning. I believe bundler was running `install` at the time. The warning header read “Get Available Generators List”, and spit out the following warnings, the first of which is “Get available generators script executes with errors”:

[image: RubyMine warnings: Get available generators script executes with errors…]

Is this telling me that I have to provide a “secret” that would make things okay with future versions of rake, or is it telling me that providing a “secret” is only a temp fix, but won’t work with future versions of rake?

How do I permanently fix this warning so I’ll be okay with rake, and take care of the vulnerability?

Comment: Do you have an initializer file in your Rails project under `config/initializers` that sets your `secret_token` variable? In my Rails 3.2.x app, which follows the standard app template, it is stored in `config/initializers/secret_token.rb`

Comment: @StuartM ty for your reply.  Yes it's there, and it is initialized with whatever it is set to out of the box.

Comment: Do you see any warnings on the command line when running `rails generate`? It's looking like a RubyMine IDE bug, similar to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-6035

Answer (score 1):

This may not answer your question if you don't use RVM or similar ruby version tool.  I believe it relates to `bundler` and gemsets, as well.

I get this too in a new project until I set Preferences > Languages and Frameworks then choose one of the several RVM-managed environments installed on my machine.

By default, it appears that RubyMine chooses the @global version of the RVM environment until I tell it otherwise.  I almost always install gems using `bundler` and `Gemfile`, so within a project there's a specific gemset (I think that's the right term) linked to it having the gems that are installed and specific to that project.  Those gems do not become available outside of the scope of the project and its gemset.  You can further isolate your project, and I recommend you do, by checking "Ignore global gempath" -- this means that your project will use exactly the same versions of gems locally as will be used when they are later deployed to production.

There are of course several gems you need to have installed globally (using `gem install`) -- `bundler`, `rake`, and `rails`, and perhaps a few others.

I don't have any answer to how one might prevent this from happening when you start a new project, but one the project has loaded, you can select the right environment and everything should work as expected.